# Default header vertical height on React Native iOS is too tall, how do I change it?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I included stack navigator in my react native app. The default vertical height of the header seems to include a vertical spacing between the back button and the status bar. How do i remove that spacing?

[image: image of header vertical height]

This is my stack navigator setup:

```
const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: 'screen' },
  default: {},
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      }
    },
    EditProfile: EditProfile,
  },
  config
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`SafeAreaView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview). The purpose of `SafeAreaView` is to render content within the safe area boundaries of a device and most importantly, Safe Area's paddings reflect the physical limitation of the screen, such as rounded corners or camera notches (i.e. the sensor housing area on iPhone X).

So you just wrap your `App`, `View`, `Page` or `Component` with the `SafeAreaView` and the padding will be set perfectly.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>Page content</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: i had <SafeAreaProvider> and <SafeAreaView>. make sure you only use one.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove it. It makes sure that your header doesn't go under the device notch.

You can use a custom header instead if you don't want it.